# Is it possible to generate a sharepoint survey link with a field automatically filled in?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have been tasked with creating a new process for our employee reviews.  The idea is that each manager will make a list of six other people to review the employee in a basic survey with three questions.  I think the easiest way to do this would be to have a survey with the three questions and a fourth question with a drop down menu for who the survey is for.  But I would prefer not to have people select from the drop down as they may select the wrong person and cause problems.  Is it possible for me to programatically generate links to surveys so that the field is already filled in for who the survey is for?  Basically each employee would have a record with six fields that have the emails of each person who will review them, then I could loop through and send an email to those six with a link to a survey with that employee already filled in.

Let me know if you need any more information or even if you have a better idea on how to achieve this task.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: @S.Walker No, we ended up having to create individual surveys for each person.

Comment: I’m glad you got something going. What you are asking is definitely possible by using JavaScript to parse query string parameters and then set the value of the drop down. This could be accomplished by editing the NewForm or EditForm or via the use of JSLink. Things also depend on if you are using the Classic or Modern list experience.